# Twilio Twimlets - Is there a way to change the voice?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am using the Twimlet to gather what button the recipient of the call presses. All that is working fine and dandy, but is there a way to change the voice of the Twimlet message to `alice`?

Her voice sounds much better than the man's and I'd like to use it all the way through my call sessions, instead of having the man's voice just during the twimlet portion.

I know how to do it in TwiML, by adding the `voice='alice'` parameter, but since Twimlets don't offer that deep of customization, is there any way for me to define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you have to put an 'echo' type of twimlet in front of your 'menu' twimlet. In the 'echo' twimlet, use ['Redirect'](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/redirect) after 'Say' to redirect to the url of your 'menu' twimlet.

Code for 'echo' twimlet:

```
<Response>
  <Say voice="alice">Hey. Press a key on your phone.</Say>
  <Redirect method="POST">[the url of your menu twimlet]</Redirect>
</Response>
```

On your 'menu' twimlet leave the message empty.

Comment: Kinda sucks you can't just use a `voice` parameter on the link. Only issue this presents is that users can't hit a menu item until after the Say occurs. But, this is a good work around, thank you!